# how to get the assigned child term of the term's parent

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I've read multiple stacks on different ways of doing this, but I've yet to find something that solves my problem. I have a parent term "Web" and a child of that term "Web Development".

The current code that I have outputs "WebWebDevelopment":

```
<?php                           
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $taxonomy = 'portfolio_categories';
    $terms = get_the_terms($id, $taxonomy);

    if( $terms ): ?>
    <div class="project-terms">
        <p><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>
        <?php
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
            foreach( $terms as $term) :
                echo $term->name;
            endforeach;
        endif;
        ?>
        </p>
    </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

I only want "Web Development".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<?php
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
      foreach( $terms as $term) :
        if ($term->parent != 0){
          echo $term->name;
        }
      endforeach;
    endif;
?>
```

In the loop of the terms it prints only terms that have a 'parent term' given by `$term->parent!=0` which means that the term is a child.

Comment: Can you explain why it works so that the OP understands the answer?

Comment: I sort of understand it, just by looking at his code, but I wouldn't know how to write that without someone showing me. Thanks. This worked. The parent part, what would happen if from `0` it was `1`? Is `1` the child?

Comment: @Darren that’s why Tom asked for some explanation to that answer... Parent is the ID of parent term. If a term has no parent, then parent field is set to 0. So this code is ignoring all terms without parent (root terms). If you would change that 0 to 1, you would ignore all terms that are children of term with ID=1.

Comment: I will add some more details later, I'm on a mobile now